# Are bounties active in Heroic Story missions?

Tags: destiny-2

With the weekly milestone to complete 3 heroic story missions and the fact you can pick the missions you'd like to complete. You'll know which planets these are on.

I'm curious to know if I visited the planets for these missions and picked up bounties there, would I be able to complete the planet bounties in those heroic story missions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounties try to be very specific about what they what you to complete, and for a good reason. It leaves it open to the player about how they want to complete it.

For example, if the bounty says "Defeat enemies on Mars using grenades." then you could be patrolling, in a strike, a nightfall, an adventure, a story mission, a weekly heroic mission, whichever. As long as you are on Mars, and not in the wrong gametype such as Crucible or Gambit, then any grenade kill will work.

Just be sure to read the requirements carefully and it should be obvious how and where to complete the bounties.

Comment: I wonder if the "Haunted Forest" would count for doing Mercury bounties. It is initiated in the tower, but it is just an alternate version of the Infinite Forest. And opening up the destination map shows you are on Mercury

Comment: I haven't tested it but seeing how it's possible to also find Mercury's planetary mats inside the Haunted Forest just like the Infinite Forest my guess is that it would work.

Comment: Keep in mind that sometimes the actual bounty has more details than are specified when buying it. It may say to kill Vex on Nessus, but after buying it you can take out your ghost and more subtext will appear saying, "Hunt down Goblins in Artifact's Edge." Not all bounties are *this* specific, of course.